# Multiple rows of buttons acting like radio buttons in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, ionic-framework

The issue here is I have three buttons per row and I need one buttons value to be save:

- eg: if the good button is clicked I need to save good and if another button is clicked, then the previous value should replace by the current value.

Exactly same for other row buttons.every buttons per row as selected should activate the buttons.

I am new to angular and i have no code to show here.

- [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLfEC.png)

Comment: Created fiddle for you.. http://jsfiddle.net/9kqrc7ap/1/ but i ve used radion button.. you can style them.. From next time onwards write full code here or just sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much @AnilKumarRam for your answer. Ya i will post sample code later on future . Thanks for your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to use radio from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

naive realisation is

```
<span ng-bind="vm.value"></span>
<button ng-click="vm.value = 1">1</button>
<button ng-click="vm.value = 2">2</button>
<button ng-click="vm.value = 3">3</button>
```